# SELECT values from TableA (and TableB if exists)

Tags: sql, select

I have a table `product_checklist` which holds checklist items. 
I want to grab this at all times, but if any list items exist for the ap_id in the table `ap_checklists` then grab `created_date`

The current statement below needs some kind of priority on the where's maybe?
is it possible to do this in one query?

```
SELECT 
    `product_checklists`.*, 
    `ap_checklists`.`ap_id`,
    `ap_checklists`.`created_date`
FROM (`product_checklists`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    `ap_checklists` ON `product_checklists`.`check_id` = `ap_checklists`.`check_id`
WHERE 
    `ap_checklists`.`ap_id` = 195 OR `product_id` = 3
GROUP BY 
    `product_checklists`.`check_process` ORDER BY `product_checklists`.`check_order`
```

Comment: What is the problem? could you post the output you get and the output you'd want? In principle the query you have should work so it is jsut a matter of fine-tunning

Comment: the query does run error free but if there is an `ap_id` less than 195 it will grab that, even when 195 exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a column in the group by or an aggregate, MySQL essentially grabs a random value for a colum.  If you use `max` it's guarantueed to pick a non-null value if available:

```
max(`ap_checklists`.`created_date`)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Where** is wrong - `ap_checklists`.`ap_id` = 195 should read

```
`product_checklists`.`ap_id` = 195
```

because you filtered right side of left join and that effectively transforms left join to inner join.

Comment: But the `where` clause uses `OR`, and `unknown or true` equals `true`

Comment: @Andomar An blatant oversight on my part. However I'm keeping this posted because I feel the intent should be to filter left side of join.

Comment: Yeah i think this is the main problem but my tables need to be structured like this. I think I'm going to have to run two queries...

Answer (score 0):

You have an bug on your where clause, because you are using a left joined table and you shouldn't

If you whant to write it in standar sql it should be:

```
FROM (`product_checklists`)     
LEFT OUTER JOIN `ap_checklists` ON `product_checklists`.`check_id` = ap_checklists`.`check_id` AND (`ap_checklists`.`ap_id` = 195 OR `product_id` = 3)
```

In Oracle's SQL you can write it as:

```
 FROM `product_checklists`, `ap_checklists` 
WHERE  `product_checklists`.`check_id` =(+) `ap_checklists`.`check_id`
  AND (`ap_checklists`.`ap_id` (+)= 195 OR `product_id` = 3)
```